# Excel 2010, how to keyboard shortcut to filter dropdown checkboxes?

Tags: excel-2010

For Excel 2010, when I have the filter drop-down open

[image: Excel Screenshot]

...how do I get to the filter checkbox section via keyboard shortcut? Skipping everything from "Sort A to Z" to the "Search" box, going all the way to the checkboxes.

Comment: the only thing I can find that works reliably (independent of how many items there are in the menu) is to press SHIT+TAB 3 times

Answer (score 12):

### Quickest Option: <kbd>e</kbd>  <kbd>↓</kbd>

In Excel 2010 (English) you just have to press <kbd>e</kbd> to get to the filter textbox; from there you can use the down arrow key  <kbd>↓</kbd>   to go to the first checkbox:

[image: Screenshot showing effect of pressing "e" and then "down"]

### Alternative Option

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>

(as mentioned by @Sean_Cheshire) - this goes "backwards" from the first entry over "Cancel" and "OK" to the first (sic!) checkbox.

### Related Question: How to *open* the filter drop-down

The question above is about how to move *inside* the filter drop-down. To *open* the filter drop-down, you have one or two options:

- **For any filter**: As @Juhi and @Josh have pointed out, you can open said menu with the keyboard when the column heading cell (where you would click to open the drop-down) is selected by typing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+ <kbd>↓</kbd>  .
- **For tables**: If you are using a [Table object](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/quick-start-create-an-excel-table-HA010359200.aspx) instead of a pivot table or regular filtered range, you can be in any row of the Table and open the filter drop-down using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+ <kbd>↓</kbd>

Comment: especially good that you added the related question, appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

ALT+DOWN arrow key opens the selection box.  Use the arrow keys to select an option and SPACEBAR to "check" or "uncheck."

Answer (score 1):

Try ALT+down. It opens the drop down list in filters and cells as well.