# What is keyboard shortcut to toggle selected items on filter drop down list?

Tags: excel, filter, keyboard-shortcuts, excel-2016

As a follow-up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13924755/excel-2010-how-to-keyboard-shortcut-to-filter-dropdown-checkboxes), is there a way to use keyboard shortcuts in Excel to select/de-select the filter drop-down check boxes? I'm not satisfied to only *arrive* at these check boxes via keyboard shortcuts. I want to know if I can actually toggle them off/on with shortcuts.

Comment: use `Space bar` to select or de-select items.

Comment: @virtualdvid Thanks - that did it! Mind adding this as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Space bar` to select or de-select items.

Answer (score 2):

This shortcuts may work. Select the column and press `ALT + Down arrow or Ctrl+Shift+L`

Comment: That's not what I'm asking...I know how to make the drop-down menu appear, but I'm wondering how I can actually select/de-select the checkboxes that appear at the bottom of the drop-down